# Explain like I'm LITERALLY five...what does it mean to "format" a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When you make a string...what does it mean to "format" that string?

CHALLENGE: Explain this to me like I'm an absolute idiot. Like, take it to a condescending level. Be mean about it. I'm talking how you would explain a lemonade stand to a very, very stupid child.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39172098/421705

Comment: it's really a broad, imprecise question, which is why it's hard to explain as simply as you request. to 'format a string' could mean any number of things depending on the context. See [http://www.blackbytes.info/2012/01/ruby-string-formatting/](http://www.blackbytes.info/2012/01/ruby-string-formatting/)

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a Question and Answer format, meaning questions should address specific programming issues and answers should be succinct and precise. Perhaps you could do better by a) researching fundamentals using a search engine before asking here or; b) taking this back to reddit where /r/ruby would be more open to receiving imprecise discussions. Please take the time to review the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking further questions.

Comment: Copy that guys, thanks for the links. Read through them both and slowly putting the pieces together...

Answer (score 2):

The most common use of the phrase refers to the replacing of variable placeholders within a string with the correct string representations of the variables' contents.

Consider:

```
temp_reading = 25.67528
puts "It is currently %0.1f degrees" % [temp_reading]

-> It is currently 25.7 degrees
```

String formatting is what turns the template into the string you see in the output.

Comment: Appreciate it, Phil! Slowly putting the pieces together...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Phil Taprogge, typically formatting a string refers to changing the representation of data for presentation reasons.

Phil's Example

```
long_number = 1.11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
puts "%0.1f" % long_number
=> 1.1

puts "%d" % long_number
=> 1
```

There is tons of documentation on string formatting and typically it can carry over to different languages since this come from the C programming language `printf`.

Formatting a string could refer, however, to any and all transformations to a string for presentation.

```
str = "hello world"
str.downcase
=> "hello world"
str.upcase
=> "HELLO WORLD"
str.capitalize
=> "Hello world"
str.titlieze
=> "Hello World"
str.parameterize
=> "hello-world"
```

https://blog.udemy.com/ruby-sprintf/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Thanks @fbelanger! This is super helpful. Just read both of your links -- I'm learning in Ruby and am SO dumb at this juncture that I (embarrassingly) didn't even realize this concept applied to other languages. Really appreciate the thorough explanation.